# What should we include in SSAS cube design documentation?

Tags: documentation, sql-server

What should we include in a SSAS cube design documentation?

This is the initial phase of the document. I have included:

- data models,
- facts,
- dimensions,
- surrogate keys,
- hierarchies and levels within hierarchies,
- reports that we can pull from the cube,
- proactive caching.

What else can we include?

Comment: Why confused, sounds like you've made a good start. I would add a users perspective by defining access roles and privileges. Maybe add administrative and maintenance schedules.

Comment: @CarloKuip I think your suggestions with some explanation on each one would make for a good answer to the question.

Comment: Does this belong here (i.e. programmers), or on DBA perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

How About the a source of the data and descriptions of all the ETL\ business rules needed to load the Cube?

It's a common misconception that to build data Cube all you need to do is learn how to model the Star Schema. But the Truth is getting all data from multiple sources, cleansed and married together in a unified format is much harder then building the cube. It mat be a good idea to document some of that stuff.

Also throw in Data Dictionary, those are always nice to have with a complex BI system.